# Python ftplib: Overwriting a File doesn't work with STOR

Tags: python, ftp, file-upload

I want to overwrite an existing file "test.txt" on my ftp server with this code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

HOST = 'host.com'
FTP_NAME = 'username'
FTP_PASS = 'password'

ftp = FTP(HOST)
ftp.login(FTP_NAME, FTP_PASS)
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
ftp.storlines('STOR test.txt', file)
ftp.quit()
file.close()
```

I don't get any error messages and the file test.txt has NOT been overwritten (the old test.txt is still on the server). I thought STOR overwrites files... Can somebody please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have write permission on the remote file?

Comment: STOR overwrite files! I check it and message is same (226-File successfully transferred). Has @BrianNeal porblem is this access on directory and you can check response message.

Answer (score 1):

nvm, it's my fault...
I forgot to change the current working directory to /public_html
thanks anyway!

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to open the file in write mode

```
file = open('test.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: No, that would just destroy the *local* copy -- the OP wants to overwrite the *server* copy!